# Error installing a module in DotNetNuke 5 - No manifest

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

We're using DotNetNuke 5.01.  I've downloaded a module from a third party company.  While installing the module using the host Module Definitions page, I get this error:

> This package does not appear to be a
>   valid DotNetNuke Extension as it does
>   not have a manifest. Old (legacy)
>   Skins and Containers do not contain
>   manifests. If this package is a legacy
>   Skin or Container Package please check
>   the appropriate radio button below,
>   and click Next.

The options are:

- Skin
- Container
- Not a Skin/Container

No matter what I choose, it loops endlessly.

Any idea what this means and how I can correct the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules need to have a file with an extension of `.dnn`.  This tells DNN the information it needs to know to properly register the module.  You may see if there are installable packages inside of the main zip archive that you tried to upload.  If not, you'll definitely want to contact the company to see how you should install the module.

Answer (score 1):

@bdukes was right, so I'm giving him the accepted answer.  In my case, I had to unzip the downloaded file to get to the *real* zip file that was the installer.

So if you get this error, try extracting everything in the zip file.  Look for a zip file in there and try installing that.